# QGIS - Creating a new polygon layer from the space between other layers

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

I wonder if it´s possible with QGIS (2.18) to create a new polygon shapefile directly from the space between Another 2 different polygon layers:

[image]

What I would like to do is to fill the gap between the two layers with a feature of a third (new) polygon shapefile. It can be done digitalizing the borders, but If there is a way to do it automatically, I could save a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following workaround where I used layers of next image (with a space between them):

[image]

1. Merge layers with **Data Management Tool -> Merge vector layers**.
2. Get polygon from layer extent (merged layer) with **Research Tools -> Polygon from layer extent**
3. Get difference for extent and merged layer: **Geoprocessing Tools -> Difference**. My result was:

[image]

As this layer is Multipart it must be converted in Singleparts: **Geometry Tools -> Multipart to singleparts**.

4. Select central feature (hole) in singleparts layer and intersect it with merged layer extent (**Geoprocessing Tools -> Intersection**). Result will be desired layer (hole); as it can be observed at following image.

[image]